# Javascript show div when all radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button, show-hide

I have a code that can show div everytime I click a radio button and it is working fine. The problem is I want all the radio button be checked and then the div will show.

Here is my code for 1 radio button

```
function showstuff(nxt){
   document.getElementById(nxtb).style.display="block";
}

<input id="ny" name="ny" type="radio" onClick="document.getElementById('ny').checked =
true; showstuff('nxt');" />

<div id="nxtb">Next</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mean- you would like ALL radio buttons to be selected to show the div and you have more than one radio button.. you may want to use checkboxes instead. If you still mean you have separate radio button options- use class instead of ID.. let me know exactly what you mean and I can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, all radio buttons, because on my form, there will be 3 question, each question has a 3 radio button, each question must be check so that the hide div which is the button will be shown. sorry I didnt explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without an obtrusive JavaScript (that is `onclick` attributes):

```
/*
 * Convert to array so we can use `forEach()` and `every()`
 */
function toArray(any) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(any);
}

var observed = toArray(document.querySelectorAll('[data-observe]'));
var listened = [];
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

/*
 * Gather all elements we want to listen for change:
 * observed elements and their siblings with the same name
 */
observed.forEach(function (target) {
    var siblings = toArray(document.querySelectorAll('[name=' + target.name +']'));
    listened = listened.concat(siblings);
});

listened.forEach(function (radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var checked = observed.every(function (item) {
            return item.checked;
        });

        checked ?
            result.removeAttribute('hidden') :
            result.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sZHAA/1/